# Do employers via Stack Overflow Jobs take your site reputation score into account?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I've eyed Stack Overflow Jobs many times as a freelancer, and I just always wondered if your account reputation score/badges were at all linked to the application process. I did search for an answer to this question via Google Search and didn't find a result.

Additionally, if you voluntarily share your Stack Overflow account, I was wondering if employers have in the past taken that into account in the hiring process (though it may be hard to say if they have, either way).  This would include looking at the nature of questions you asked and answered and how they relate to the job you applied for.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Employers can see your Stack Overflow reputation, but they're not necessarily looking at it.

We do show your rep score on the employer view of your Developer Story, if you choose to display it. That is, if you add your rep to your Story in the Story editor, and then apply for a job using your Story or declare yourself as "Actively Looking" or "Passively Looking" (so you can be found by recruiters searching our database for candidates), then employers can see your rep.

However, I get the impression from people on our Customer Success team (who, unlike me, *actually talk* to our customers every day) that most employers don't put too much stock in a candidate's rep. [My esteemed colleague Amy](https://twitter.com/schraual?lang=en) says

> No one ever asks me about it. If they're in the top percentage for [a given tag], that's another story. If they see in the results that someone is in the top % for a technology they're searching, that's really interesting/exciting to them.

In other words recruiters tend to be less interested in reputation and more interested in your experience with a particular technology, along with your work history, open source contributions, etc. (Of course, that varies from person to person.) That said, in training conversations with recruiters, we do try to discourage them from taking top percentiles too seriously: there are plenty of skilled developers who aren't highly ranked, simply because they don't have the spare time to put in the hundreds of hours it takes to achieve a high rep.

I'd love to give you hard stats, but we haven't run a formal employer survey and sadly we don't have data on which part of the page a recruiter's eyes are looking at. We are working on that technology though, and I'm excited to announce that all new customers will be required to undergo compulsory brain-implant surgery starting in 2018.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, as well as humor.

Comment: So they cannot directly see your user profile in the site?

Comment: Your Stack Overflow contributions are publicly accessible data, so, yeah, a dedicated recruiter could try to figure out who your SO user is based on information in your Dev Story. (In my case that'd be pretty easy because I'm using my real name, plus, my Dev Story contains links to Stack Overflow answers I've written.) I don't think it happens very often in practice though. Recruiters are busy people and their priority is typically to get a quick impression of whether a candidate is worth interviewing, not to dig through everything you've ever done in detail.

Comment: They may not care during the initial phases, but when they have to decide among several candidates from SO johs, I'm sure they will check everything out including SO and your social media profile.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Just to be clear, there is only a direct link to our SO user profiles if we select one or more from the "Pick the network sites you want to display" section in the setup/edit? Your first sentence seems to say employers can see everyone's profile, but later in your answer it seems like the user has control over it.

Comment: @tehDorf Yes. They can only see what you decide to put on your Story. You can click on the "Share your Developer Story" links on the right to see what it'd look like to an employer.

Answer (score 14):

Yes they can, and in at least some cases they do.

I can state with certainty that when I interviewed for my current job (which had been advertised here on SO) at least a couple of the people who interviewed me made it clear that they'd looked through my profile and at least some of the answers I'd posted.

In fact, one of the interviews was devoted primarily to (what was at the time) my top-voted answer in a fair amount of detail, and discussing exactly why it was as useful/effective as it was.