# Plans for compulsory brain-implant surgery?

Tags: discussion

We [recently learned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350331/290085) that Stack Overflow Jobs has developed a new technology:

> I'm excited to announce that all new customers will be required to
>   undergo compulsory brain-implant surgery starting in 2018.

Are there plans to apply this in other ways?  Is Stack Exchange Inc open to suggestions?

Comment: Is it Friday already?

Comment: OP must be from Iceland, @rene

Comment: Given your edits to my answer, I suspect you know first hand how painful one is, @ryanyuyu

Comment: Man.  I walked right into that one @Oded.  Worth it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Absolutely.  You are welcome to suggest more things.

We do have the following in the plan:

Robotic limbs, AI implants, and most importantly, humorectomies.

Comment: I'm told the latter were made possible by a research grant from the German ministry of science and development.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - very possible. Either that or via handbag sales.

Comment: I would *never* invest in such a ghastly technology!

Comment: Ah, so that explains the decline in pun titles for burnination requests...

Comment: Has anyone considered the possibility that these upgrades would interfere with people's dance dance authentication?

Comment: It could be that those went towards extra robotic limbs - you know, to carry more handbags, @Pekka웃

Comment: @Don'tPanic - robotic limbs will add accuracy to dance moves.

Comment: @Oded accuracy would certainly render my dance moves unrecognizable.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - agreed - biometrics may suffer.