# Does job application require reputation?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

I want to know if I must reach a specific reputation before I can apply for a job in Stack Overflow.

Do the employers check your reputation? Are the reputation and badges a factor to be considered while giving you the job? How does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't require reputation. I'm told most employers (I assume you mean employers and not employees) do not care much about reputation.

Comment: 1. No 2. Maybe, depends on the employer, no one here will be able to tell you because no one knows what an individual employer may or may not do 3. ditto

Comment: @Oded `I'm told most employers ...  do not care much about reputation` NOW YOU TELL ME

Comment: Some of them care about handbags, though - @Pekka웃

Comment: @Oded that's good to know!

Comment: Yes very good to know @Oded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need any rep to apply to a job. In fact, you don't need a Stack Overflow account. If you are logged in however, and you have a Developer Story, we'll include a link to your Developer Story with your application. You can view what employer see by clicking the 'Story view' or 'Traditional view' links on the right side of the Developer Story editor.

[image]

As for checking rep, Ben went into much more detail [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350331/5516513).