# Does our Answers and Badges earned take counts for hiring

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, profile-page, careers-select

How does most of the companies look at the candidates' profile for shortlisting.

It may be anything like on LinkedIn, Online Job portals and soon...

Does Stack Overflow really bridge the career gap during long or short term breakage?

Since I have heard man fixing a issues to build his career, but I never heard issues fixes a man's career life? Does it happen in reality?

Certainly in one way or another it had helped me a lot.

Asking a question not only clarifies the problem several times to ourselves. But it builds our meta cognitive skills to deal with the answer to our own questions (AKA rubber duck debugging).

While answering, we try to understand the nature of the problem **at least twice** to digest and discover what you need to find out before jumping into find a solution to the given problem.

From the client perspective, we are showing our natural ability and capability to deal with a proper solution.

Apart from it: How will it be benefit the candidate relevant to his/her carrer?
How does a project manager, TL, HR or any other individual's look to hire such a candidate?
What are the pros and cons relevant to the above subject?

Comment: Related: [Do employers via Stack Overflow Jobs take your site reputation score into account?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350330/2675154)

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to give a blanket answer here because hiring differs rather vastly between cultures. I can summarize what I've said in the past in conversations about this as it's all pretty relevant to what you're asking, even if it doesn't *directly* answer your question - I'm not sure if any single answer would, though.

It's not just badges and points, Stack Overflow gives hiring managers a really good overview of how well you communicate with your peers, how well you thrive in our kind of structure, and how engaged you are with programming in general (thus spending time helping others in your spare time). All of that is great to display, and *you* should feel good about it.

But, who does the hiring where you live? If it's someone that writes code, all of that stuff *really* matters .. but if it's just someone screening CVs and looking for certain kinds of badges, well, it could be wasted signal. The whole hiring process is already way too old, yet so many companies still expect it to be useful - it's going to take time until everyone catches up.

So if you sit and think about every *good* thing someone could learn from looking at your participation, well, it starts to mount up. But it's really up to you to make *sure* companies see it, which means you have to write your letters and CV in a way that really points it out.

And again, this is going to vary wildly from US to Asia and other places, culture is a big part of it. Not *exactly* the answer I think you were hoping for, but I'm not sure I could give a single complete answer to it when a big chunk of it really boils down to 'it depends'.

It's *one* good source of signal about you, but so is your GitHub repo, your blog, the maker club you tweet about quite often, etc, etc - if that makes sense.