# Does Stack Overflow give awards, like MVP?

Tags: discussion

While listening to a YouTube movie, a person presented himself as being proud for being a so-called MVP, a Microsoft Most-Valuable Professional.

As I'm quite active on Stack Overflow, this made me curious, so from the MVP Wikipedia page, I went to the [page, containing the "List of computer-related awards"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer-related_awards), and I found nothing related to Stack Overflow.

Does, next to the reputation, Stack Overflow give awards for active members and are those awards generally accepted outsite of the scope of the Stack Exchange websites? (It might become handy mentioning this on a CV, as you might imagine.)

**Edit:** (some extra background)
Several years ago, some people graduated as MCSE (Microsoft Certified System Engineer), which was something very valuable, as it was a grade, received after following a formal education. I was expecting MVP do be something similar, but not that official (like a kind of award for "altruistic" work instead of "selfish" education), hence my question.

Comment: There's already reputation, repuation leagues, and tag badges (ex. getting a gold tag badge for a specific language). There's also a lot of activity on the site that's quite hard to quantify (such as curation activities). What exactly would the value of a hypothetical MVP-like award be, that isn't redundant with what we have now?

Comment: I would most definitely not mention in the CV that I have X reputation on SO. That metric is completely useless.

Comment: As an aside, being a Microsoft MVP is generally not a good mark unless you're planning to work at MS. MVPs have just told people to reinstall windows a sufficient amount of times, because Microsoft has no standards on who they make MVPs. And don't get me started on the plagiarism machines in some other categories (notably the Azure department). More awards != more gooder

Comment: I guess the only MVP on Stack Overflow is [Jon Skeet, who received a painting from Stack Overflow... in 2010](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/01/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/)

Comment: Its kind of apples and oranges isn't it? Oracle does something like that, Microsoft does something like that - comparable companies with comparable business strategies. Stack Overflow is something very different.

Comment: @Gimby: it's not that apples and oranges: Oracle does something like this, Microsoft does something like that, and StackOverflow covers both Oracle and Microsoft technologies, so one might think of a joint effort for Stack Overflow to also do something like that, that was my idea.

Comment: probably related: [The problem with extrinsic motivation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42481/165773)

Comment: Everyone is given access to a flair badge that can be used on other sites/profiles to show off your unicorn points.

Comment: "It might become handy mentioning this on a CV, as you might imagine" - the https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350330/do-employers-via-stack-overflow-jobs-take-your-site-reputation-score-into-accoun may be an educational read. I don't have really high rep, which may be the reason I never got asked about it in interviews... And I definitely did not see that being used why I'm part of interviews.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine not every MVP "told people to reinstall Windows"... [some](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/10/30/mvp-again/) even visit SO :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: No, there is not a MVP-style award for Stack Overflow.

Things like high reputation, badges (particularly gold badges), highly-voted answers, and being elected as a moderator, might serve as a stand-in for such a thing.

Comment: "and being elected as a moderator" - not for anything technical. Being technically competent doesn't make someone a good mod. The rest of the list contains far better metrics at displaying technical knowledge, which is what MVPs are (on paper, disregarding the bit where MS doesn't actually enforce that with standards in practice)

Comment: That’s fair. I think I was focusing on the statement “like a kind of award for ’altruistic’ work instead of ’selfish’ education”.  I guess it depends what behavior you’re looking to highlight.